# Resizing multiple images for web use

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

I am using Photoshop CC 2015. 
We have several hundred images that need to be sized for web use. I have a 1,000 x 1,000 pixel template that I normally use to manually resize the images. It is quite time consuming & I'd really like to have a script or action to do it.
I've tried doing it with image processor but it's not quite what I need. I want them all to be sized to fit a 1,000 x 1,000 template AND I want the canvas to be 1,000 x 1,000. I hope this makes sense! Seems like there must be some sort of shortcut for this!

Thank you!
Dottie

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in Photoshop fairly easily: Create an action with a step for resizing the image to the desired size then saving, then batch apply the action to all the files (file > batch).

However, an even easier option would be to just get a resizing app, there are quite a few good ones, some even free.